# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode' scrapy for python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, httpresponse

I am working with response in scrapy and keep on getting this message.

I only gave the snippet where the error is occuring. I am trying to go through different webpages and need get the # of pages in that particular webpage. So I created A response object where I  get the href for the next button but keep on getting `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'`

code working with.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapingtest.items import ScrapingTestingItem
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
from scrapy.selector.lxmlsel import HtmlXPathSelector
import csv
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Response

class scrapingtestspider(Spider):
    name = "scrapytesting"
    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.in"]
 #   base_uri = ["tripadvisor.in"]

    def start_requests(self):
        site_array=["http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g3581633-d2290190-Reviews-Corbett_Treetop_Riverview-Marchula_Jim_Corbett_National_Park_Uttarakhand.html"
                    "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297600-d8029162-Reviews-Daman_Casa_Tesoro-Daman_Daman_and_Diu.html",
                    "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304557-d2519662-Reviews-Darjeeling_Khushalaya_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Darjeeling_West_Bengal.html",
                    "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g319724-d3795261-Reviews-Dharamshala_The_Sanctuary_A_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Dharamsala_Himachal_Pradesh.html",
                    "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g1544623-d8029274-Reviews-Dindi_By_The_Godavari-Nalgonda_Andhra_Pradesh.html"]

        for i in range(len(site_array)):
            response = Response(url=site_array[i])
            sites = Selector(response).xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract()
 #           sites = response.selector.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract()
            for site in sites:
                yield Request(site_array[i],self.parse)
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the line where your error occurs expects a `TextResponse` object not a normal response. Try to create a `TextResponse` instead of the normal `Response` to resolve the error.

The missing method is documented [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.body_as_unicode).

More specifically use an `HtmlResponse` because your response would be some HTML and not plain text. `HtmlResponse` is a subclass of `TextResponse` so it inherits the missing method.

**One more thing**: where do you set the body of your `Response`? Without any body your `xpath` query will return nothing. As far as in the example in your question you only set the URL but no body. This is why your `xpath` returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks, Works as in gives no error. But the Xpath returns nothing. Will need to figure that out. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the answer in the meantime. I think it is related to the type of the `Response`: `TextResponse` has no structured data but an `HtmlResponse` or `XmlResponse` has. Try one of those.

Comment: I tried the HtmlResponse but the xpath returns an array length of 0, which it should not as there is a Next @href. But as I said it works, need to figure out the other problem

Comment: I am also parsing in an url from a selfmade url array.

Comment: Cannot figure out, htmlresponse seems to be getting the webpage but the xpath returns nothing

Comment: I realize this is an old post but I've had the same problem when scraping sites- prepending my URLs with "http://render.import.io/?url=" has been a huge help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 2022 response since this question pops up first in Google on the error.

`TextResponse.body_as_unicode`  has been deprecated and removed ([link](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/55ae2109c95e497d4a730afeb9caf71aa78a7723)), so use `TextResponse.text` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This does not really answer to this question but can be used to find the problem with the response object returned. I am adding it as an answer so that it might help someone debug the problem they are facing.

I had encountered a similar error: `AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'text'` when I did:

```
scrapy shell 'http://example.com'
>>>response.text
```

To find out what was the problem I checked out the attributes present in the response object returned using:

```
response.__dict__
```

However, `__dict__` does not return attributes that are attached due to an object's parent class.

The response object that I received had the attribute `_body` which contained the html for that page.

Comment: Beautiful. This helped me debug issues with a single page application not loading section of the page fast enough, and also see the HTML on the page. Very useful when you're trying to figure out running scrapy+splash on a new site.