# Selector returns nothing in scrapy for python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working with `htmlResponse` and `selector`, `htmlResponse` returns the site `<200 "site">` but when I check the Selector(response) it says `<Selector xpath=None data=u'<html></html>'>` even though the `htmlResponse` returns this

```
<200 http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g3581633-d2290190-Reviews-Corbett_Tr
eetop_Riverview-Marchula_Jim_Corbett_National_Park_Uttarakhand.htmlhttp://www.tr
ipadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297600-d8029162-Reviews-Daman_Casa_Tesoro-Daman_Daman
_and_Diu.html>
```

Code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapingtest.items import ScrapingTestingItem
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
from scrapy.selector.lxmlsel import HtmlXPathSelector
import csv
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class scrapingtestspider(Spider):
    name = "scrapytesting"
    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.in"]
 #   base_uri = ["tripadvisor.in"]
def start_requests(self):
    site_array=["http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g3581633-d2290190-Reviews-Corbett_Treetop_Riverview-Marchula_Jim_Corbett_National_Park_Uttarakhand.html"
                "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297600-d8029162-Reviews-Daman_Casa_Tesoro-Daman_Daman_and_Diu.html",
                "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304557-d2519662-Reviews-Darjeeling_Khushalaya_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Darjeeling_West_Bengal.html",
                "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g319724-d3795261-Reviews-Dharamshala_The_Sanctuary_A_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Dharamsala_Himachal_Pradesh.html",
                "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g1544623-d8029274-Reviews-Dindi_By_The_Godavari-Nalgonda_Andhra_Pradesh.html"]

    for i in range(len(site_array)):
        response = HtmlResponse(site_array[i])
        sels = Selector(response)
        sites = sels.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract()
        print "________________________________________________________________"
        print sels
        print "________________________________________________________________"
        if(sites and len(sites) > 0):
            for site in sites:
                yield Request(site_array[i],self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647048/3941341) you do not set the body of the `Response` object.

Why don't you `yield` a new `Request` with the URLs of your `site_array` to let Scrapy scrape them? What you currently are doing won't work out.

Naturally in this case you need to adjust your parser method or write a new one and add it as a `callback` to the `Request` (I would do the second version).

Comment: Crap yes forgot the body. Wow waste of a question. and as far as yielding a new request goes it will call it all at once. and what do you set the body as?

Comment: In your case you do not have the body so you need either to `yield Request` or use some alternative way to get the content (for example with `urlopen`).